# how to unpack list(list()) in scala

Tags: scala, nested-lists, flatten

Hi I am beginner in scala, 
I  want to unpack

```
List(List("hello=10","hi=21","there=13","bro=44","family=44","technology=35","hi=20","hello=100","hi=21","there=13","bro=44","family=44","technology=35","hi=21","there=13","bro=44","family=44","family=44"))
```

into something like

```
List("hello=10","hi=21","there=13","bro=44","family=44","technology=35","hi=20","hello=100","hi=21","there=13","bro=44","family=44","technology=35","hi=21","there=13","bro=44","family=44","family=44")
```

how we can achive?

Thanks!

Comment: use `flatten` method

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in method flatten of list.

```
scala> val list = List(List("hello=10","hi=21","there=13","bro=44","family=44","technology=35","hi=20","hello=100","hi=21","there=13","bro=44","family=44","technology=35","hi=21","there=13","bro=44","family=44","family=44"))
list: List[List[String]] = List(List(hello=10, hi=21, there=13, bro=44, family=44, technology=35, hi=20, hello=100, hi=21, there=13, bro=44, family=44, technology=35, hi=21, there=13, bro=44, family=44, family=44))

scala> list.flatten
res0: List[String] = List(hello=10, hi=21, there=13, bro=44, family=44, technology=35, hi=20, hello=100, hi=21, there=13, bro=44, family=44, technology=35, hi=21, there=13, bro=44, family=44, family=44)
```